# Is it possible to define a type "AnyClass" that exclude objects that were not constructed via "new Class"?

Tags: typescript

In my use case I need to pass a class instance to a function

```
myFunction(instance: ???, callback: () => void)
```

If I put `Object` as type I can send anything there from `{}` to `() => {}` and typescript will not complain.

I need to just send new created objects like:

```
myClass = new MyClass()
myFunction(myClass, () => console.log('ok'));
```

is this possible? 
please notice that Use `MyClass` as type is not possible since there are a lot of possible classes to send. Also use generics is not possible since it has to replace an already existing function.

concrete example

```
import myFuntion ....
class MyClass {

   executeFunction() : void {
       myFunction(this, () => console.log('ok'));
   }
}
```

Edit: I can not edit the classes to add an interface or similar.

`instance` is an Angular @Component, @Injectable, @Directive, @Pipe. Anything that can have an `OnDestroy` BUT does not necessary have one. (part of the function is to check that).

Comment: Would using an interface be an option for you? So you define an interface and every class you want to pass needs to implement this.

Comment: Not really, because then I would have to modify all of those (100s of classes) :(

Comment: what do you use the `instance` for in `myFunction`? can you provide body of `myFunction`

Comment: Hm, then I see no way to handle that (except using `Object`), but that does not mean that there is no such way of course.

Comment: It is an Angular @Component, @Injectable, @Directive, or @Pipe (also, anything that can have an `onDestroy` (but not necessary has there). Sadly because of the new rules of SO and that the code is propertary I can not pasted it completelly.

Comment: Maybe you can create an example at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Can someone even tell the difference between `{}` and `new Object()`?  That is, I don't think that `new` leaves some kind of "mark" on an object instance that can be consulted later and distinguishes it from any other object.  If you had a particular parent class you cared about you might be able to do it, but there might not be a meaningful distinction between constructed and "non-constructed" objects.  

Comment: Hi @jcalz, to be honest, I already thought this  can not be done but I wanted to ask to see if there was some special thing I just don't know about that could help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
const x = {};

x instanceof Object; //true
```

Or even:

```
const x = {onDestroy: () => {}}

x instanceof Object; //true
```

So, a little cheeky answer to your question if you'll excuse me, is: every object is instance of some class. (*There might be some javascript esoteric that I am not aware of but lets assume this is true for now*).

Moreover, you are trying to workaround typescript duck typing, which I found impossible in this case.

The best function definition as far as I was able to come up with was,

```
function myFunction(instance: { onDestroy?: () => void }, callback: () => void): any;
```

Following are legal:

```
class Hello {
    onDestroy() {   }
}

class Bye { }

myFunction(new Hello(), () => {})

myFunction(new Bye(), () => {})

myFunction({}, () => {})

myFunction({onDestroy: () => {}}, () => {})
```

Following are illegal:

```
myFunction(null, () => {})

myFunction([], () => {})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

based on comments if you want to call `onDestroy` then what about doing it like this

```
myFunction(instance: { onDestroy: () => void }, callback: () => void)
```

Comment: The problem is that `onDestroy` could not be defined, if not I will create it. If yes I will wrap it.

Comment: so may be I didn't get what do you want to do, please create a stackblitz and share it